# Load stylesheet in edit category page?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, css

I have a plugin that I want to add a stylesheet to each "edit category" page because I added additional custom fields into those pages.

Is there a simple way of doing this or do I have to use the URL and add it individually using `add_action()`?

Answer (score 1):

The way to enqueue admin styles and scripts in targeted pages is explained here:
[Difference between do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix) and do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix") syntax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/49993/12615)

The Category page is the same as the Tag page, `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php`. So, an extra check is needed and in this case using the global variable `$current_screen`.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit-tags.php', function(){
    global $current_screen;

    // Not categories, do nothing
    if( 'edit-category' != $current_screen->id )
        return;

    // Debug
    echo "<script>alert('$current_screen->id')</script>";

    // wp_enqueue_style() call here
});
```